# Multiple Custom Views in ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

Is it possible to add multiple custom views into an Action Bar?

I tried to set two custom views in the Action Bar by using,

```
ActionBar.setCustomView(view);
```

, but it seems there is one view can be seen at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to add multiple custom views into an Action Bar?

Not directly. You can either:

- Wrap them in a horizontal `LinearLayout` or something and use `setCustomView()`
- Migrate one or more of them to be action views/action layouts/action providers on an `<item>` in the action bar

Also, bear in mind that the action bar is pretty small on phones in portrait mode, so bigger stuff may not fit all that well.

Comment: ok, I have two `EditText` views, & I have enabled Split Action Bar When Narrowed. Is it possible to wrap in a `LinearLayout` & show in Action Bar such that the one view is shown in top Action Bar & other is shown in bottom Action Bar?

Comment: @pawan_vimukthi: No, but if you use `setCustomView()` for one and have the other one be an action view/action layout/action provider on an `<item>`, they should wind up separated. Action items go in the split bar at the bottom; the custom navigation `View` should go in the top.